# Is changing the class type back after loading from storyboard dangerous?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

Let's say I have a `storyboard` scene that has a `UIViewController` in it with its custom class set to `ParentViewController`. I'd like to create a `ChildViewController` that does almost everything the same as `ParentViewController` but customizes just a few behaviors. `ParentViewController`'s `init` loads the scene from the storyboard.

What I have now is `ChildViewController` subclassing `ParentViewController`. When `ChildViewController`'s `init` calls `ParentViewController`'s `init` through [super init], the ParentViewController loads the scene which in turn makes my class a `ParentViewController` even though it was a `ChildViewController`. After that the ParentViewController's methods get called.

I can get around that by using a strategy pattern, giving the view controller objects that customize the behavior as needed. But the code I'm working in also keys off of the Class types, so I really need a `ChildViewController` to stay a `ChildViewController`, or logic down the line does the wrong thing.

Question 1: In this case is it safe to use `object_setClass` to set the class back to what it was?

Question 2: If I do that do I not need the strategy any more? I assume once the class is set back the proper subclass methods will be called.

I'm just concerned that changing the class when the framework changed it for me in the first place might break something else.

Comment: you can make you own different initializer methods for both class and call [super init]; in both methods, by this you will be able to call UIViewController class's init method in both the classes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm pretty new to storyboards, so I'm probably just missing something, but right now the parent view controller's init is calling self = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"CoursesTab" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DiscussionsTab"]; which is what causes the class type of the child controller to change. Is there a different way to load the storyboard that won't do that? Remember that the storyboard has the controller instantiated in it. Or maybe that's the problem?